# Proving $f_n\rightarrow f$ such that $\sup_n \| f_n \|_1 \leq K$ implies $\| f \|_1\leq K$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Looking back at my notes from class, I see:

**Claim.** $f_n\rightarrow f$ such that $\sup_n \| f_n \|_1 \leq K$ implies $\| f \|_1\leq K$.

It appears after the statement and proof of Fatou's lemma but I can't see how to prove it that way. How should I proceed?

Answer (score 1):

Ah, I think the following works. $f_n\rightarrow f$ implies $|f_n|\rightarrow |f|$ and then by Fatou $\liminf _n \|f_n \|_1\geq \|f_1\|_1$. But the sequence in the LHS is bounded, which means the LHS is finite, and therefore so is the RHS.